# Creating a complex excel worksheet in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am working on a project that researches into book records as cataloged in libraries. For a part of the analysis, I need to create an excel sheet with many regions like the following:
[image: An example of a region (out of many) I need to create in an Excel worksheet]

The data for these structure are stored in a database, and I'm using python.
Being a Pandas-newbee, I tried to see if I can do this through dataFrames/mulitIndexes, but from the tutorials I have been following so far, I am doubtful this is the best way, because, as you can see from the screen-dump, the row/columns are not very regular.

Should I rather use openpyxl for that task? Or some other API/stack I have not yet encountered?

Comment: You should share a sample of your data (can be dummy data), so that people can understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks! The Excel sheet actually contains a sample of my  data. It is the transition to excel that is the headache. Michael